# rpy2.tests, no item called "None" on the search list

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using Rpy2 and running the tests using $python -m "rpy2.tests". I got the following errors. I am using ubuntu 14.03, python 2.7 and trying to calling R in python using this package.

```
    rpy2 version: 2.6.0
    - built against R version: 3-2.1--68531
    - running linked to R version: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
    ....../tmp/tmpRWL4lU.py:17: UserWarning: 

      ri.baseenv['eval'](ri.parse(rcode))
    ..................................................................................................................................................................................x.........................................................................................................E
    Stderr:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py:80: UserWarning: Error in as.environment(where) : no item called "None" on the search list

      StrSexpVector((cls_packagename, )))
    E...................................sssssssss................................E.s...s..s.....
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: testRS4Auto_Type (robjects.tests.testMethods.MethodsTestCase)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/tests/testMethods.py", line 115, in testRS4Auto_Type
        robjects.methods.RS4)):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 617, in with_metaclass
        return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py", line 154, in __new__
        cls_def = getclassdef(cls_rname, cls_rpackagename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py", line 80, in getclassdef
        StrSexpVector((cls_packagename, )))
    RRuntimeError: Error in as.environment(where) : no item called "None" on the search list


    Stderr:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py:80: UserWarning: Error in as.environment(where) : no item called "None" on the search list

      StrSexpVector((cls_packagename, )))

    ======================================================================
    ERROR: testRS4Auto_Type_nopackname (robjects.tests.testMethods.MethodsTestCase)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/tests/testMethods.py", line 122, in testRS4Auto_Type_nopackname
        robjects.methods.RS4)):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 617, in with_metaclass
        return meta("NewBase", bases, {})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py", line 154, in __new__
        cls_def = getclassdef(cls_rname, cls_rpackagename)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/methods.py", line 80, in getclassdef
        StrSexpVector((cls_packagename, )))
    RRuntimeError: Error in as.environment(where) : no item called "None" on the search list


    ======================================================================
    ERROR: test_Rconverter (ipython.tests.test_rmagic.TestRmagic)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/ipython/tests/test_rmagic.py", line 127, in test_Rconverter
        tuple(fromr_dataf_np.ix[col_i].values))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 418, in __getattribute__
        raise AttributeError("record array has no attribute %s" % attr)
    AttributeError: record array has no attribute ix

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 383 tests in 3.719s

    FAILED (errors=3, skipped=12, expected failures=1)
```

Any ideas to fix these three errors?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you how R and/or rpy2 where installed ?